# How to create Unwind segue programmatically

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue, unwind-segue

I make an application using no storyboard and in this part of my app I need to create a unwind segue from `ThirdViewController` to `FirstViewController` programmatically only. I know how to do it using sotorybard but can't find any solution how to do it programmatically. Any sugestions?

Comment: You say "_createGenerally you would have an unwind segue defined on your storyboard and then `performSegueWithIdentifier` programmatically. Is there any reason you can't do that?

Comment: Yes. All app is make in code, main storyboard is empty.

Comment: Are you using a UINavigationController or are the viewControllers presented modally?  Is there a SecondViewController between the first and third?

Comment: Yes, I am using `UINavigationController` and between the first and third one  is `SecondViewController`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create an actual *segue* without a Storyboard, but you can do the equivalent action by calling `popToViewController` on `navigationController`.  Here is an example that is connected to a button to return to `FirstViewController` from `ThirdViewController`:

```
@IBAction func goBackToFirstVC(sender: UIButton) {
    guard let controllers = navigationController?.viewControllers else { return }
    let count = controllers.count
    if count > 2 {
        // Third from the last is the viewController we want
        if let firstVC = controllers[count - 3] as? FirstViewController {
            // pass back some data
            firstVC.someProperty = someData
            firstVC.someOtherProperty = moreData

            navigationController?.popToViewController(firstVC, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

In an override of `viewWillAppear`, you can act upon that data that was passed back.

Comment: it is perfect solution and first which works! Thanks a lot!